# combinatoric permutation

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Assume you want to omit all multiples of n and all multiples of m from the set: {1,2,3,...,k} where n,m and k are natural numbers. what would be the right formula to calculate the outcome after omitting all multiples of n and m?

Comment: What should your final result be? The set of all remaining numbers?

Comment: Are you looking for a logical/set-thepretic expression for doing this, or do you want to know how many elements are left in the set, or ...?

Comment: @Bram28, set of final results, plus the formula explaining how we got it. Set theoretical expression would be optimal. Thanks

Comment: @platty set of final results, plus the formula explaining how we got it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you are looking for, but if you are looking for a set-theoretic/logical expression to describe this set:

$$\{ i \in \mathbb{N} | 1 \le i \land i \le k \land \neg \exists j (j\cdot n = i \lor j \cdot m = i) \}$$

For a formula of how many numbers are in that set, we can say that there are roughly $k/m$ numbers that are multiples of $m$, and there are roughly $k/n$ numbers that are multiples of $n$, and with $lcm(m,n)$ being the least common multiple of $m$ and $n$, there are roughly $k/lcm(m,n)$ numbers that are multiples of both $m$ and $n$.  So: you end up removing $k/m + k/n - k/lcm(m,n)$ numbers, leaving you with:

$$k - k/m - k/n + k/lcm(m,n)$$

Example:

$k =100$

$m = 6$

$n =15$

We have $16$ multiples of $6$ between $1$ and $100$, and $6$ multiples of $15$. Also, their least common multiple is $30$, and there are $3$ numbers that are multiple of $30$. So, you end up removing $16+6-3=19$ numbers, leaving you with $81$.

For an exact formula, use the floor function:

We remove $\lfloor k/m \rfloor  + \lfloor k/n \rfloor- \lfloor k / lcm(m,n)\rfloor$ numbers, leaving you with:

$$k - \lfloor k/m \rfloor  - \lfloor k/n \rfloor + \lfloor k / lcm(m,n)\rfloor$$

Comment: Thanks for set theoretic expression,what I am looking for is this: Dealing with the set of $k$ numbers, as explained above, when we consider $m$, then we omit $1/m$ numbers from the set so we have $l=k-1/m$ remaining numbers. when we further deal with $n$ then we need to remove $1/n$ from the remaining set ($l$), does this mean that we now have $l-1/n$ remaining in the set?

Comment: @bijankarimi OK, so you are looking for a formula of the size of the resulting set then?  OK, I'll have to think about that, but what you say is not right, because by removing the multiples of $m$, you may be removing multiples of $n$ as well, so you can't say that you end up removing $1/n$ from the set $l$ (besides, more often than not $k/n$ and $k/m$ are not whole numbers ...)

Comment: @bijankarimi Example: $k = 16$, $m = 2$, $n = 4$. Even though $k/m$ and $k/n$ are nice numbers, after removing all the multiple of $m$, you clearly don't remove anything else when trying to remove the multiples of $n$ after that.

Comment: Yes. In fact when removing multiples of $m$, we remove also multiples like $n.m$. Let us add another assumption: n and m are both prime numbers.

Comment: @bijankarimi And different :)

Comment: @bijankarimi But you could still be removing duplicates, e.g. $k =100$, $m = 3$, $n =17$ Now look at $51$ ...

Comment: @bijankarimi In other words, you need to consider the Least Common Multiple ($lcm(m,n)$), and see how many of those you have between $1$ and $k$: they get 'removed twice', so you would need to add those back in, so you get (roughly ... again, you may not be dealing with whole numbers here): Number of numbers removed = $k/m + k/n -k/lcm(m,n)$